# Button that update my application without play store

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, refresh, auto-update

i've make an application with 10 fragment with tableLayout..
I would like a button that update all the layout without having to update the application each time the play store.. is it possible?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do that.** It is possible if your application declares the necessary rights in its manifest (to install applications). But expect that no sane user would install your software afterwards, as that would allow your application to install malware and other stuff also.

Besides that, you surely don't want to replicate all the necessary infrastructure to send notifications to users, have them download your app all at the same time...

Instead think of how to create the layout dynamically in code.

Comment: sin, I wanted create a button similar to twitter application, did an upgrade all my layout without having to update the application in the play store..